# Pyspark .toPandas() results in object column where expected numeric one

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, parquet

I extact data from our datawarehouse, store this in a parquet file and load all the parquet files into a spark dataframe.
So far so good. However when I try to plot this using pandas.plot() function it throws me a "TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot"

So I started investigating backwards to my source and I think the cast to decimal from my initial sql statement is one of the issues. But I have no clue how to fix this. I thought a fillna(0) would do the trick, but it doesn't.

**STEP 1: Define the SQL statement to extract the data**

```
mpr_sql = """
select 
CAST(DATE_KEY  AS INTEGER) AS DATE_KEY ,
CAST(AMD  AS INTEGER) AS AMD ,
CAST(AMD_2  AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS AMD_2 ,
CAST(AMD_3  AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS AMD_3 ,
CAST(AMD_4  AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS AMD_4 ,
CAST(AMD_0  AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS AMD_0 
"""
```

**STEP 2: Create a spark dataframe from the extracted data**

```
df1 = sqlContext.load(source="jdbc", 
                         driver="com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver", 
                         url=db_url,
                         user=db_user
                         TMODE="TERA",
                         password=db_pwd,
                         dbtable="( "+sql+") a")
```

**STEP 3: Store the spark dataframe in a parquet file with 10 partitions**

```
df1.coalesce(10).write.parquet("./mpr"+month+"sorted.parquet")
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('./mpr*sorted.parquet')
```

**STEP 4: look at the spark dataframe schema (it shows decimal(12,2))**

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- DATE_KEY: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AMD:   integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AMD_2: decimal(12,2) (nullable = true)
 |-- AMD_3: decimal(12,2) (nullable = true)
 |-- AMD_4: decimal(12,2) (nullable = true)
 |-- AMD_0: decimal(12,2) (nullable = true)
```

**STEP 5: convert the spark dataframe into a pandas dataframe and replace any Nulls by 0 (with the fillna(0))**

```
pdf=df.fillna(0).toPandas()
```

**STEP 6: look at the pandas dataframe info for the relevant columns. AMD is correct (integer), but AMD_4 is of type object where I expected a double or float or something like that (sorry always forget the right type). And since AMD_4 is a non numeric type, I can not use it to be plotted.**

```
pdf[['AMD','AMD4']].info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 20 entries, 20140101 to 20150801
Data columns (total 2 columns):
AMD         20 non-null int64
AMD_4       20 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 480.0+ bytes
```

**So my questions are:**

1. Why is the AMD_4 (and the other AMD_x columns not shown here) of type object, while AMD is of typ int64?
2. Or in other words how can I make the AMD_x columns in a float/double/decimal kind of type

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and then I figured out what was the reason.

During the conversion, there is a coalesce of data types, such as int/long -> int64, double -> float64, string->obj. For all unknown data types, it will be converted to obj type.

In Pandas data frame, there is no decimal data type, so all columns of decimal data type are converted to obj type.

If you can convert all decimal data type to double type before applying toPandas(), you will have all numerical data ready to use.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df = df.withColumn('AMD_4', col('AMD_4').cast(DoubleType())).withColumn('AMD_2', col('AMD_2').cast(DoubleType()))
pdf = df.toPandas()
```

In the pdf, the AMD_4 and AMD_2 will be numerical now.

Answer (score 3):

First check `pdf.isnull().sum()`:
1.It should be all zero. For some reason, if some column count returns na or nan, you can always use pandas `fillna()`,

```
pdf = df.fillna(0).toPandas()
pdf = pdf.fillna(0)
```

or

```
pdf=df.toPandas().fillna(0)
```

2.If all were zeros then, check where is type mismatch with,

```
pdf.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)))
```

And correct it

Comment: the wrecked columns are of type class decimal.Decimal .. I can change that using pdf.applymap(lambda x: float(x) if ( isinstance(x, (Decimal))) else x). However I still don't understand why the spark dataframe to pandas results in an object of class decimal.Decimal and is not usable directly. Any idea on how to fix that, should I do a different initial cast in my extraction SQL? Since this is still the time for me to fix it, before making all my extracts.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with spark though its strange, since only one column has this problem.